# Xarray KeyError: the index is unsorted or non-unique

Tags: dataframe, python-xarray

I have an Xarray, which contains Sentinel-2 satellite images. Based on this [Stackstac example](https://stackstac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic.html), I am trying to crop my AOI using loc:

`aoi = da.loc[..., y_utm + m_buffer:y_utm - m_buffer, x_utm - m_buffer:x_utm + m_buffer]`

This is producing an error:

```
keyerror: "cannot represent labeled-based slice indexer for coordinate 'time' with a slice over integer positions; the index is unsorted or non-unique
```

I have tried sorting the index:

`da = da.sortby('time')`

...and also dropping any duplicates in time:

```
_, index = np.unique(da['time'], return_index=True)
da.isel(time=index)
```

But these do not resolve the error. Any help appreciated.

Update: printing out the time values, they are sorted, but there is also one missing value. How can I remove this?

```
 '2022-11-22T18:04:02.003000000' '2022-11-25T18:13:57.149000000'
 '2022-11-27T18:04:01.065000000' '2022-11-30T18:13:56.264000000'
 '2022-12-10T18:13:54.658000000' '2022-12-15T18:13:57.458000000'
 '2022-12-17T18:04:00.671000000'                           'NaT']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error with netcdf data from CMEMS in xarray. My solution was to drop duplicate time values. You may try a similar approach and try dropping NaTs:

```
nc = xr.open_dataset(*url to data*)    
nc = nc.dropna(dim='time')
```

The documentation is [here](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.dropna.html#xarray.DataArray.dropna).